# except / try clause to error check the user for a bad color string?

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

If the user enters a bad color string into the dragon fractal program that I made, of course it will crash. My solution was this:

```
while True:
    try:
        color = turtle.textinput('You can ride it!','What color dragon would you like?')
        break
    except:
        color = turtle.textinput('Try again?!?!?!','Dragons don\'t come in that color :P')
```

but the except statement is never triggered, (and no, saying bad color string in front of the except clause does not help) because I guess the bad color string error is not build into the except clause. Any help?

Comment: How can you decide if a color is valid or not? Do you have a list of valid colors?

Answer (score 0):

`try`-`except` is used to catch errors.The part of code that causes the error must be put into the `try` block.If an error occurs in the try part,the except part will be executed.

```
while True:
    try:
        color = turtle.textinput('You can ride it!','What color dragon would you like?')
        #code that causes error,or raises exception,maybe code to ride a dragon 
        #that has an invalid color
    except:
        color = turtle.textinput('Try again?!?!?!','Dragons don\'t come in that color :P')
```

And you wont need the `break` statement in `try` block.

Further the above code snippet has a bug.If the user enters the wrong color twice,then your
program will crash again,as the error is not caught in the `except` block.A workaround would be to use some sort of alert saying the color is invalid in the `except` part and reading input only at the `try` part

Comment: As a general rule, you're right about the "bug". However, textinput will not raise exceptions, so in the current implementation it won't do any harm.

Comment: thanks a lot! this really helped. By the way, the code is for generating a dragon fractal :)

Answer (score 0):

The input will always be valid. `turtle.textinput` does not raise errors, it will always return the input, or `None` if nothing entered.

Try the following:

```
while True:
    try:
        color = turtle.textinput('You can ride it!','What color dragon would you like?')
        turtle.pencolor(color)
        break
    except:
        color = turtle.textinput('Try again?!?!?!','Dragons don\'t come in that color :P')
```

Notice there is another problem, that if you go to the exception, the input will be discarded. This is because you're not breaking from the loop in the `except`, so you'll get back to the `try` block once the user has written something. Perhaps that's what you've intended to do, but then there's no point in the `color =` there.

Comment: turtle.textinput() does raise errors. It raises a special turtle error. This is exactly my problem, because the except statement doesn't seem to register such a thing as being an exception

Comment: Can you post the traceback? If there isn't one, then how do you get the error on input?

Comment: Sure, I just edited it. I am not working on this program anymore, but I would be interested to know the answer